# Why registerAllowedOrderSigner function doesnt work

Tags: web3js, 0x, cryptography, defi, dapp-debugging

i created a limit order. Then what I wanted is to give access to another address who can sign the order on behalf of me.
I called the registerAllowedOrderSigner method from the proxy contract and passed the signer ADDRESS.
After transaction is successful ,I validated it by calling isValidSigner function and it gave true as an output.

Then I signed the order with the signer address. After verifying the signature by calling getLimitOrderRelevantState, it returned invalid signature.

https://gist.github.com/Saty248/5533043f43a8ec29e5b168a8878212fe  .

this is the link of the github gist for my code along with the output for better understanding.